# Laravel - File Upload button not working in live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

In the laravel project the file upload button was working fine during local development using WAMP Server. But when I uploaded the project to my shared hosting server, the file upload button does not work anymore. The button is disabled.

In my localhost the upload button works, but in my live server the file upload button does not work(disabled)

Pls help I don't know what to do.

in my controller, here is the code for upload

```
public function upload(Request $request){

    $type = array(
        "jpg"=>"image",
        "jpeg"=>"image",
        "png"=>"image",
        "svg"=>"image",
        "webp"=>"image",
        "gif"=>"image",
        "mp4"=>"video",
        "mpg"=>"video",
        "mpeg"=>"video",
        "webm"=>"video",
        "ogg"=>"video",
        "avi"=>"video",
        "mov"=>"video",
        "flv"=>"video",
        "swf"=>"video",
        "mkv"=>"video",
        "wmv"=>"video",
        "wma"=>"audio",
        "aac"=>"audio",
        "wav"=>"audio",
        "mp3"=>"audio",
        "zip"=>"archive",
        "rar"=>"archive",
        "7z"=>"archive",
        "doc"=>"document",
        "txt"=>"document",
        "docx"=>"document",
        "pdf"=>"document",
        "csv"=>"document",
        "xml"=>"document",
        "ods"=>"document",
        "xlr"=>"document",
        "xls"=>"document",
        "xlsx"=>"document"
    );

    if($request->hasFile('aiz_file')){
        $upload = new Upload;
        $upload->file_original_name = null;

        $arr = explode('.', $request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalName());

        for($i=0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++){
            if($i == 0){
                $upload->file_original_name .= $arr[$i];
            }
            else{
                $upload->file_original_name .= ".".$arr[$i];
            }
        }

        $upload->file_name = $request->file('aiz_file')->store('uploads/all');
        $upload->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $upload->extension = $request->file('aiz_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if(isset($type[$upload->extension])){
            $upload->type = $type[$upload->extension];
        }
        else{
            $upload->type = "others";
        }
        $upload->file_size = $request->file('aiz_file')->getSize();
        $upload->save();

        return '{}';
    }
}
```

in my view, here is the code that handles the upload

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="types">{{translate('System Logo - White')}}</label>
                        <div class="input-group" data-toggle="aizuploader" data-type="image">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text bg-soft-secondary">{{ translate('Browse') }}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control file-amount">{{ translate('Choose Files') }}</div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="system_logo_white" value="{{ get_setting('system_logo_white') }}" class="selected-files">
                        </div>
```

Comment: I think we still missing some context because from what you post your input is hidden. Are you using javascript to trigger it? Otherwise just replace type hidden with file.

Comment: I am using javascript to trigger @Castro Alhodo

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help you since i don't have the context. But here is some clues if you are using laravel to post image. Look at the csrf token. Second clue look at the protocol some javascript library require https. Laravel would not disable your button unless you literally wanna do that. So it's more likely on your javascript. Look at the form if you use multipart. If you can post a sample with the whole context.  Maybe i can help you more.

Comment: @Castro I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the laravel .env file, the url was not properly set. So I had to correct it and it worked.

Old url - http://example.com

New url - https://example.com/ (working  url)